# Who would qualify as the youngest Avatar

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

If Avatar Kyoshi was the oldest Avatar, who would qualify as the youngest Avatar. Would it be Aang?

Comment: Aren't they avatars as soon as they are born?

Comment: Maybe I should of said the youngest avatar to have mastered the four elements and the Avatar State

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean the youngest to master all four elements, this doesn't seem to be addressed explicitly so far. Most likely Aang, but still, there's no mention of that I think.

However, there are two bits of evidence suggesting that it was indeed Aang:

---

**No one expects the avatar to master the four elements early.**

At the beginning of *The Legend of Korra*, when Korra is done with her firebending demonstration, she urges the elders to let her move on to airbending. The elders respond that she is rushing things too much.

So the elders are *not expecting* Korra to master all four elements yet. This suggests that, historically, it is uncommon for an avatar to master them at an early age.

---

**Roku mastered the elements until his adulthood.**

We also know that Roku was already an adult when he was still training, according to the visions he shows Aang.

---

The above clues suggest that it is not normal for an avatar to master the elements early. Aang did so at the age of 12, with only one year of training.

The reason both Aang and Wan mastered the four elements in a short period of time was because they were under much pressure (Vaatu and Sozin's comet), so maybe another avatar also did this even earlier - however, we don't know of other "big events" that would require an avatar to master the elements so quickly.

---

Conclusion is - most likely Aang, but unconfirmed.

Comment: When Aang visits Roku at the Fire Temple, Aang is concerned about learning all of the elements before the comet arrives. The context of their conversation is about learning the elements before the end of the following summer, but Roku seems to [strongly imply](https://youtu.be/kgKRH-_G0ds?t=16m30s) that the Avatar has been in a similar situation and has done it before. This seems to imply that a previous incarnation was young and had to learn all 4 elements in an expedited timeframe. So, it is feasible that Aang is not the youngest, although the other avatar(s) are unknown.